# How to Create Sidebar Menu in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

How to create a UI like below using JavaFX (fxml + css)? I am more interested about the sidebar menu component. An extensive Google search does not yield any resources on how to achieve it.

[image]

JavaFx control libraries like ControlFX or JFoenix do not provides anything like this sidebar menu.

Comment: see [create a vertical menu ribbon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717343/javafx-create-a-vertical-menu-ribbon)

Comment: @rvit34 its not quite the same I was looking for. Vertical menu ribbon is just some styled border less buttons in a stack pane. What I am really looking for is a menu structure with sub menus (something like a treeview). Similar looking control would be Android's navigation drawer.

Comment: Use a `BorderPane` as a root node, set `VBox` (VerticalBox) on the left side of the root node, then add buttons to the vbox.

Comment: @AnindyaChatterjee use [TreeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) then with some CSS customizations

Comment: I have used [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601900/javafx-how-to-create-slide-in-animation-effect-for-a-pane-inside-a-transparent) with great success.